# c# FileStream Read having problems with StreamReader EndOfStream

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader

As the title says I found a problem. Little back story first:
We have `file.txt` looking like this:

```
aaaabb
ccccddd
eeeefffffff
```

There are many ways to read this text line-by-line, one of which is this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt");
while(!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string s = sr.ReadLine();
}
sr.Close();
```

Works. `s` gets each line. 
Now I need the first 4 letters as bytes and the rest as string. After looking up things and experimenting a little, I found that the easiest way is this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
byte[] arr = new byte[4];
fs.Read(arr, 0, 4);
string s = sr.ReadLine();
sr.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Works. `arr` contains the first 4 letters as bytes and the rest of the line is saved in `s`. This is only a single line. If we add the `while`:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
while(!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[4];
    fs.Read(arr, 0, 4);
    string s = sr.ReadLine();
} 
sr.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Now there's a problem. Now `arr` doesn't get anything and `s` reads the whole line including the first 4 letters. Even more strange that if I use `while(true)` (and I assume anything else that is not the example) than it works as intended, 4 characters as bytes and rest is string, and this is the same for every line.

Question is that what am I missing? Why is this happening? How do I solve this? Or is it possible that this is a bug?

Comment: you read in array from `fs` and read the rest of the line from `sr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is simple buffering. When you attach your `StreamReader` to the `FileStream`, it ends up consuming a block from the file, thus advancing the current `Position` of `FileStream`. With your example file and the default buffer size, once the `StreamReader` attaches itself, it basically consumes the entire file into a buffer, leaving the `FileStream` at its EOF. When you then attempt to read 4 bytes from the `FileStream` directly via your `fs` reference, there's nothing left to consume. The following `ReadLine` works on your `sr` reference as that's reading from the buffered file content.

Here's a step-by-step breakdown of what's happening:

1. `fs` opens up the file and sits at `Position` 0.
2. `sr` wraps up `fs` and the call to `EndOfStream` ends up consuming (in this case) 27 bytes into its internal buffer. At this point, the `fs` `Position` now sits at EOF.
3. You attempt to read from `fs` directly, but its at EOF with no more bytes.
4. `sr.ReadLine` reads from the buffer it built up in step #2 and all works well.

To fix your specific error case, you could change your byte array to a char array and use `sr.Read` instead. i.e.

```
char[] arr = new char[4];
sr.Read(arr, 0, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you. I just only want to say that it seems as this consumption only happens when sr.Something used or maybe similar. That's why while sr inicialised, it is still posibble to use fs.Read(), but after sr.ReadLine() or sr.EndOfStream, fs.Read() will stop giving result.

Also yes I deleted it because I did some tests incorrectly and assumed wrong facts. So to not keep false information, I simply decided to delete it.

Answer (score 4):

> Now there's a problem. Now arr doesn't get anything and s reads the whole line including the first 4 letters.

Yes, that seems very plausible. `StreamReader` maintains a buffer - when you ask it to read a line of text, it may well read *more* from the stream than that single line, using that buffered data when it's next asked for information.

Fundamentally, I would strongly advise from directly reading from the stream that the `StreamReader` is reading from. It's going to be very fiddly to get right even where it's possible, and in some cases the API may just not let you do what you want.

If you want to remove the first four characters from each line, it would be *much* simpler to read the whole line, and then use `Substring`.